# Update propertie value in directive

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I'm trying to create my own directive to count input length value.

- on view init I'm add with my directive the maxlength attribute with value send to the directive --> ok
- on after view init I add a div before my directive with the count like 0/50 --> ok

I just have a problem for updating the length value when I use my keybord (the property is updated but not the render).
Can you help me please?

```
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, OnInit, Renderer2
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appInputmaxLength]'
})
export class InputmaxLengthDirective implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @Input() appInputmaxLength: string;
  private currentValue = 0;

  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ) {}

  @HostListener('keydown') isChange() {
    let countNb = this.el.nativeElement.value.length + 1;
    if (countNb <= 1) {
      this.currentValue = 0;
    } else {
      this.currentValue = countNb;
    }

    console.log('test: ', this.el.nativeElement.value.length + 1);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'maxLength', this.appInputmaxLength);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const html = '<div>' + this.currentValue + ' / ' + this.appInputmaxLength + '</div>'
    const target = this.el;
    target.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', html);
  }

}
```

this is how i used the directive:

```
<input type="text" [appInputmaxLength]="'5'" />
```

Thanks you for your help, I'm lost.

Comment: Could you also provide an example of how you are using this directive ?

Comment: Done i have edit my post

Answer (score 1):

**[Here is a Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-maxlength-directive) of the directive**

I made a few modifications to your code to make, here is what I suggest:

- Change your `appInputMaxLength` type to number
- Use the `Renderer2` API as much as you can bo be cross-platform compatible.
- Use a private `div` property to hold your div and update it later, create it with `this.renderer.createElement('div')`
- Use `this.renderer.insertBefore(this.el.nativeElement.parentNode, this.div, this.el.nativeElement.nextSibling)` to insert it after the host
- Listen to changes using the `input` event, and get the value from the event, then get its length and update the `div`
- You don't need to keep a `currentValue` variable, just get the length from the input's value or event
- Use `this.renderer.setProperty(this.div, 'innerText', ...);` to update the text of your div element
- Remove the div element since Angular won't keep track of it. For this you cannot use `this.renderer.removeChild(this.el.nativeElement.parent, this.div)` since `ngOnDestroy` is called after the DOM has been removed and the `parent` reference will then be null. You have to directly call `this.div.remove()` ([see this github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14252)).

### Updated directive code

```
import { AfterViewInit, Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, OnInit, Renderer2, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appInputMaxLength]'
})
export class InputMaxLengthDirective implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() appInputMaxLength: number;
  private div: HTMLDivElement;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  @HostListener('input', ['$event']) onChange(event) {
    this.update(event.target.value.length);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'maxLength', this.appInputMaxLength.toString());
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.div) {
      this.div.remove();
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.div = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    this.renderer.insertBefore(this.el.nativeElement.parentNode, this.div, this.el.nativeElement.nextSibling);
    this.update(this.el.nativeElement.value.length);
  }

  private update(length: number) {
    this.renderer.setProperty(this.div, 'innerText', `${length} / ${this.appInputMaxLength}`);
  }
}
```

Use it like this, with a number input value:

```
<input type="text" [appInputMaxLength]="10">
```

---

### Directive code compatible with ngModel

If you want your directive to work when an `ngModel` is bound to the input and update accordingly if the model changes, you can get by injection the host `ngModel` and then subscribe to its `valueChange` observable:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, OnInit, Renderer2, Optional, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appInputMaxLength]'
})
export class InputMaxLengthDirective implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() appInputMaxLength: number;
  private div: HTMLDivElement;
  private destroyed$ = new Subject();

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2, @Optional() private ngModel: NgModel) {}

  @HostListener('input', ['$event']) onChange(event) {
    if (!this.ngModel) {
      this.update(event.target.value.length);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'maxLength', this.appInputMaxLength.toString());
    if (this.ngModel) {
      this.ngModel.valueChanges.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$)).subscribe(value => {
        this.update(value.length);
      })
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.div = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    this.renderer.insertBefore(this.el.nativeElement.parentNode, this.div, this.el.nativeElement.nextSibling);
    this.update(this.el.nativeElement.value.length);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroyed$.next();
    this.destroyed$.complete();
    if (this.div) {
      this.div.remove();
    }
  }

  private update(length: number) {
    this.renderer.setProperty(this.div, 'innerText', `${length} / ${this.appInputMaxLength}`);
  }
}
```

Then you can use your directive on an input with an `ngModel`:

```
<input type="text" [appInputMaxLength]="10" [(ngModel)]="value">
```

Comment: Ok all working good thank you for the tip for detect change all :)

Comment: @orphen92300, I updated the answer and the stackblitz to handle the case when your input is destroyed (with ngIf for example). Now the div is properly removed

Comment: @orphen92300, does that answer your question ?

Answer (score 0):

try this code i have rewritten the some codes

```
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  HostListener,
  Input,
  OnInit,
  Renderer2,
  OnDestroy
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appInputmaxLength]'
})
export class InputmaxLengthDirective implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() appInputmaxLength: string;
  private currentValue = 0;
  countDiv: HTMLDivElement;
  parent: any;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  @HostListener('keyup') isChange() {
    const countNb = this.el.nativeElement.value.length + 1;
    if (countNb <= 1) {
      this.currentValue = 0;
      this.updateCount();
    } else {
      this.currentValue = countNb;
      this.updateCount();
    }

    console.log('test: ', this.el.nativeElement.value.length + 1);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'maxLength', this.appInputmaxLength);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.renderer.removeChild(this.parent, this.countDiv);
    this.renderer.destroyNode(this.countDiv);
  }

  updateCount() {
    this.countDiv.innerText = this.currentValue + ' / ' + this.appInputmaxLength;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.countDiv = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    this.parent = this.renderer.parentNode(this.el.nativeElement);
    this.renderer.appendChild(parent, this.countDiv);
    this.updateCount();
  }
}
```

in this code i'm using renderer to create a div element and updating its value wherever the `currentValue` changes.

Also you have to destroy it when directive destroyed to avoid memory leak

Comment: thanks you its working.
I have change the keydown with Key up.
I just have a last problem the div is create inside the input and not after. How can i do that please ?

Comment: please check the `ngAfterViewInit()` there I'm getting parent

Answer (score 0):

the right way is to use a setter. The setter function is called every time the input changes.

```
    @Input() set appInputmaxLength(value:string){
    // Your code here
    console.log(value);
    }
```

An example can be found here: https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives (You directive is not a structural directive, but it's in this example)